Unbalanced nested quotation marks with [french]{babel} and csquotes
I am using both [french]{babel} and csquotes. I get some unexpected behavior resulting il unbalanced quotation marks:
\enquote{Oui, mais \enquote{non}} yields « Oui, mais « non » (notice a single closing guillemet and wrong quotation marks at the nested level.
Using the babel \frquote command, things come out OK: \frquote{Oui, mais \frquote{non}} yields « Oui, mais "non" ».
Here is my test code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Oui, mais \enquote{non}} (wrong)\hfill % « Oui, mais « non »
\frquote{Oui, mais \frquote{non}} (right).\\    % « Oui, mais "non" »
\end{document}

Is there something I am doing wrong ? Thanks!

from the definition it looks as if that is by design. The code tries to avoid that two guillements are in a row. You can avoid that with \def\initfrenchquotes{}.

You should set french=quotes. From the manual, page 35:

All variants of the french style use spaced out guillemets as outer marks. The style variant quotes uses double quotes as inner marks.

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % pdfLaTeX only
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Oui, mais \enquote{non}} (wrong)\par     % « Oui, mais « non »
\frquote{Oui, mais \frquote{non}} (right).        % « Oui, mais "non" »
\end{document}

Result:

Note that it still looks like a bug, as the regular style should balance the guillemets, i.e.,
« Oui, mais « non » ».
This is not related to babel though, with polyglossia the same issue occurs.

I understand you prefer having the same quotation mark for embedded quotations. Some authors prefer having different marks:  Aurel Ramat, "Le Ramat de la typographie" recommends what you consider wrong.  Jean Méron prefers single chevron : « Oui, mais ‹ non › ».  The later can be achieved with \frquote by adding \frenchsetup{InnerGuillSingle} to the preamble.

@DanielFlipo the 'wrong' and 'right' remarks (that I copied from the OP and forgot to change) are not about which symbol to use for the inner quote, it refers to the fact that in the original code the guillemets were unbalanced (there are two open guillemets signs before Oui and before non, but only one closing guillemets sign). It would be nice if this bug in \enquote was fixed somehow.

Sorry, I misunderstood your point.  There is nothing wrong with the  regular option french=guillemets: it is recommended by the French "Imprimerie Nationale" to delete the internal final » when the outer and inner quotations end together.  This only applies of course when the same quotation marks are used for both quotations.
